# How to repeatedly/automatically setup ansible server itself

Tags: ansible

I'm setting up a ansible server and I have a basic question.

**What is  the best practice regarding setting up the first ansible server itself ?** (Installing specific version's python, ansible, etc.)

Ansible server is used to setup other non-ansible (and ansible servers),
but the first/root ansible server can't be helped by any ansible servers.

I'm writing a shell script just for the first one but I'm feeling I'm in early 2000.

Comment: In case you face any issues in your script, then share the script and the respective issue in the question to get further help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the information you require to setup ansible at the below given links,

[WATCH ANSIBLE QUICK START VIDEO](https://www.ansible.com/resources/get-started#)

[HOW ANSIBLE WORKS](https://www.ansible.com/overview/how-ansible-works)

[DOWNLOAD ANSIBLE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue. I solved it in the following way:

1. Set up the first server manually (bear with me!) to a bare Ansible control server.
2. Create a second server with only the OS, no Ansible yet.
3. Write scripts on the first server to build up the second server to a fully specced Ansible control server. I did need to have an extra (shell)-script that installs the required galaxy roles. You can use Ansible to have those roles automatically installed on the second server.
4. On the second server, pull (you're Ansible scripts are in version control right?) the scripts and use them to keep the first server uptodate.
5. Switch regularly between using the first and second server as Ansible control server.

Yes, this does indeed add overhead (extra server, extra switching). But this way you make sure that when both servers die, you only need to have a first simple server with a bare Ansible and either build up itself or a second server.